# Facebook login issue in my android app

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I have facebook login integrated in my app.
The login was working fine and i recently didn't land any code changes on fb integration
but recently am facing this issue

When i tap the login button, nothing happens

The log shows the error reason as access_denied

Log:

```
https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=65667677&signed_next=1&next=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&scope=email&type=user_agent&client_id=65667677&ret=login&cancel_uri=fbconnect://success?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&display=touch
```

I really don't know what is causing the issue
Kindly pls help me out of this

Comment: Where is your login code..

Comment: you may have used a different keystore to sign the app. :/